# On automorphism group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ be a finite
field of order $p$. Let $U_{n}$ denote the unitriangular group of $n\times n$ upper
triangular matrices with ones on the diagonal, over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Are there groups such as their automorphism group is $U_{n}$?.

Any example or reference will be helpful. Thank you all.

Comment: If $p=2$, it seems possible that $Aut(U_n)=U_n$... Although maybe I'm just not seeing some outer auts...

Comment: @Nick Gill: I thought that Gaschutz proved that ${\rm Out}(P)$ has order divisible by $p$ for any finite $p$-group $P$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Is this a $p$-group, though?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It has $p^{n(n-1)/2}$ elements, so yes.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki :Yes, $U_{n}$ is always a $p$-group. If $p^{k}$ is the smallest power of $p$ greater than or equal to $n$, we have $u^{p^{k}} = I$ for each $u \in U_{n}.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, What about $C_p$?

Comment: D'oh; those make sense. I'm not sure what i was thinking, mea culpa. :/ Can I blame a lack of coffee this morning?

Comment: @Nick Gill: Clearly, that is a counterexample, so I mis-remembered the theorem. Maybe these are the only counterexamples, but I need to look up the theorem.

Comment: @NickGill:  It seems that groups of order $p$ are the only exceptions to Gaschutz's theorem.

Comment: $U_3(p=2)\cong D_8\cong Aut(D_8)$.